# TestCafe Click Spawned Pop Up to Save CSV File

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I can't find any way to click "Save" on a pop up that spawns during a test.  TestCafe needs to click the "Save" button so I can obtain the CSV file.

I've tried searching for a way to do this in the docs but the closest thing I found so far is .pressKey('enter').  However, this fails to click 'Save' and I don't know what other options I have.

Screenshot of exactly what I'm trying to click:

enter image description here

I provided the end of my code (you'll have to assume all the prior parts of a TestCafe test are preceeding this:

```
.click(export_button)
.click(csv_pill)
.wait(3000)
.pressKey('enter')
```

I expect to somehow be able to have the mouse detect this 'Save' button and it clicks it to save this CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe cannot test native browser dialogs. They should be prevented. If you encountered this behavior during the test, please create a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) with a simple example page or link to a tested site.

Comment: Artem, please have a look at this https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/interact-with-webapps-save-as-dialog/520/5 where it appears AndreyBelym was able to get the saveas pop up to save properly but in that case he knew what the filename will be but in my case, the filename will always be variable since it's producing a timestamped filename (varying each time you reach the point of saveas).  If Testcafe cannot test native browser dialogs, how is it working in AndreyBelym's example?

Comment: Andrey Belym mentioned that the `Save as` dialog won't be shown, and TestCafe will start downloading into the default Downloads folder immediately. It's expected behavior, since TestCafe can not handle native dialogs. If you encountered this dialog, it appears to be a bug. Please share your project to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: In the end I had to use a combination of Python with TestCafe.  TestCafe to trigger the download button to appear (as in screenshot) and then, after successful test, the window closes yet the download window remains lol.  From that point, I have python's pyautogui move the mouse to the expected place on the screen to complete the task of clicking that 'Save' button.